# How to save Borderlands 2 characters online

Tags: borderlands-2, xbox-one

My friend and I have been playing Borderlands 2 online on the Xbox for months. Today he's coming here at my place and we want to have a session together.
If I make him log with his account on my Xbox, will he be able to use his character?

Answer (score 0):

If the operation is the same as on PC your characters are saved online. It's necessary to launch the game (and the game session) on the account who hosted for the first time the game, otherwise you will spawn in the first mission of the game (with your character).

Comment: not accurate. as far as i'm aware, regardless of the platform, it doesn't matter who starts the game if you both ended in the same spot. the only possible difference is a level variation, where the host player is what determines the level of everything else around them.

Answer (score 0):

yes, your characters are saved online. as long as you make sure that both accounts are signed in *and* that you have a stable Internet connection for it to sync, you'll be fine